# Outlook 2007 - How to save Address book entries as Contacts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts, address-book

In Outlook 2007, what is the way to save Address book entries as Contacts?
The "Add to contacts" option under Address book's file menu is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is greyed out is possibly becuase it is missing or corrupt. Try this article out on re-installing it...

http://softwaremagician.com/blog/?p=17

I have had similar problems why users in the past....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 2007, but I used to have a problem with 2003 where the default was actually pointing to an improper file. Once I set the proper file, all was okay. Sorry I can't be more helpful.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the MS Address Book application? If so, you can drag-and-drop contacts from Address Book to Outlook Contacts, by dropping a contact onto the Contacts entry on the navigation pane.

Answer (score 0):

That *is* the way to save address book entries as contacts.

You're encountering some type of error, but we'd need some more information to figure out what the cause is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you select any entry in the address book? If not the "Add to contacts" option is grayed out.